# QComboBox retains mouse hover highlight if you close popup

Tags: qt, hover, qcombobox

I am having some issues styling my QComboBoxes. I want to have them highlight when mouse over, but it seems they retain the highlight if I click on them and then close the pop-up (either by clicking outside or by selecting something, does not matter). I am using Qt 5.13.1 and I see this issue on macOS and Linux. Haven't tested on others but I guess it would be the same.

My style is this simple, maybe I am missing something:

```
QComboBox:hover
{
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for? Or do you mean the hover color of the QComboBox when you did not yet press to view all the other options?

```
QComboBox QAbstractItemView
{
  selection-color: white;
  selection-background-color: black;
}
```

EDIT (after reading the comments):

Right click on the combobox in the designer space and chose go to slot.
Then press CurrentIndexChanged(int) and change the code of the slot to this:

```
void MainWindow::on_comboBox_currentIndexChanged(int index)
{
    ui->comboBox->setStyleSheet("QComboBox:!editable, QComboBox::drop-down:editable {"
                                "background: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1,"
                                "stop: 0 #E1E1E1, stop: 0.4 #DDDDDD,"
                                "stop: 0.5 #D8D8D8, stop: 1.0 #D3D3D3);}");
}
```

Comment: Yes, I mean after the popup is closed the combobox is left as if it is hovered. It can be reset by actually hovering over it then getting the mouse out of it's area again.

Comment: You could try this: 
void MainWindow::on_comboBox_currentIndexChanged(int index)
{
    ui->comboBox->setStyleSheet("QComboBox {color: white;background-color:blue}");
}
Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @Lucifer893 I think I've found what you needed in the Qt docs. Let me know if this was what you were looking for.

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately it doesn't work. In theory it should work in the case of actually selecting something from the list, but it doesn't. I believe it to be a bug in Qt at the moment

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I managed to work around this issue, will write it here in case anybody else has this problem. I quit trying to use qss and did it in the code. Subclassed the QComboBox and added the hover events:

```
bool TrackableComboBox::event(QEvent *event)
{
    switch (event->type())
    {
        case QEvent::Enter:
            this->setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);");
            break;
        case QEvent::Leave:
        case QEvent::MouseButtonPress:
            this->setStyleSheet("background-color: -1;");
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return QWidget::event(event);
}
```

The secret here is to add Leave and MouseButtonPress reset the color, otherwise you will have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this with Qt 5, seems indeed a Qt bug.

I noticed it with a class derived from QWidget when a custom context menu is shown. It seems the hover state is not updated when another window gets focus.

I could fix it by simply posting a `QLeaveEvent` and calling `update()` when the popup was triggered.

This is the contextmen slot declaration in **customwidget.h**:

```cpp
    protected:
      void contextMenuEvent(QContextMenuEvent* event) override;
```

This is the implementation in **customwidget.cpp**. Remember to `#include <QApplication>` and post the event when you need to reset the hover state:

```
void CustomWidget::contextMenuEvent(QContextMenuEvent* event) {
    event->accept();
    // do stuff
    // this is a custom menu
    m_pMenu->popup(event->globalPos());
    // Unset the hover state manually
    QEvent lev = QEvent(QEvent::Leave);
    QApplication::sendEvent(this, &lev);
    update();
}
```